# Как заменить повторяющиеся слова в PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, текст, клавиатура, замена

Как заменить повторяющиеся слова в `PhpStorm`?

Аналог сочетания <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> в `Sublime Text`.

Comment: напишите что дано и что надо. не все знают что там делает ctrl-d в sublime. для рефакторинга есть shift+f6, для замен есть ctrl+H

Answer (score 1):

В идее это делается так: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

[image: Ctrl+Shift+R]

Уверен, что в `PhpStorm` аналогичная система.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы массово заменить в файле : Ctrl +R ->replace all

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, в Sublime `Ctrl+D` - это **Quick Add Next** при работе с multiple carets.Его аналог в PHPStorm - **Add Selection for Next Occurrence**, `Alt+J` в раскладке по умолчанию (для Windows, для других операционных систем могут использоваться другие шорткаты). См.  https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/